# Get a string value from a data table row using the data table's first row as identifier

Tags: c#

I have searched several threads and cannot seem to find a C# solution.  I have a string list and a datatable in C#.  I need to be able to iterate through my data table's rows, then iterate through my list to obtain a header value (`row[0]`) and use that to assign to a variable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private void setInformation(DataTable dt, List<string> text)
    {

       foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {

         if (dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0)
           {

              for (int i = 0; i <= text.Count; i++)
                {
                  string s;
                  string ValueNeeded; 

                  s = text[i];

                 ValueNeeded = dt.Columns.IndexOf(text).ToString(); 
                 //needs to be the current dt rows value for the header / 
                 //row(0) with that string identifier

                 //in VB its something like 
                 //DT.Rows(0).Item(text).ToString
                  }
              }
       }
}
```

All I have is the first row's string value; as I iterate through the DT, I'll need to get that "cell's value by leveraging the first rows value. I need the current cell each time.

Comment: It looks like your code is missing some curly braces. Please [edit] your code to include the missing characters, and add proper indentation.

Comment: Appologies... got happy with the enter button

Comment: @Matt, just a suggestions, try name your variables properly, so it is easier to read and understand your code

Comment: _i <= text.Count_ will cause an IndexOutOfRangeException later on in your code

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. What do you mean by header/row[0]? if you're always looking at the first row, why are you looping through all rows?

Comment: `foreach(DataRowView row in dt.Rows ) { ValueNeeded = row["ColumnName"]}` might be one approach

Comment: Sorry ... all i'll have is the first row's string value; as i iterate through the DT, i'll need to get that "cell's value by leveraging the first rows value.  i need the current cell each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of any cell by referencing the row[index] and the column name string

```
string xyz= dt.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString();
```

Comment: This is the "first" column name string correct? Row 0.. because i've tried this and it does not seem to work.  for example, on the "fifth" iteration of the dt, i'll be on row 4 and a string "foo".  All i'll have is dt's 0 cell string; not "foo."  I need to get "foo" only using the row and its "first" row string (element 0 in the dt rows)

Comment: It's a public property so it must be there, try this link https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/437500/find-column-name-by-index-in-datatable-row

Answer (score 1):

OK so assuming the `List<string> text` parameter contains values of the *first row* (not the column names) in your DataTable, and you're looking to get the corresponding cell in each row, something like this should work (haven't tested it)

```
private void setInformation(DataTable dt, List<string> text)
{
    var cache = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //cache column numbers
    foreach(var entry in text) cache[entry] = getColumnNumberByValue(dt, entry);

    for(int i=1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach(var entry in text)
        {
            var columnIndex = cache[entry];
            if(columnIndex != -1)
            {
                var valueNeeded = dt.Rows[i][columnIndex].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

private int getColumnNumberByValue(DataTable dataTable, string text)
{
    for(int i=0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(dataTable.Rows[0][i].ToString() == text) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: ok, try the solution above. The basic idea is to fond the column index corresponding to each value in the string list, then use that when looping through the data table